# ApplicationContext is always null

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, spring-3, applicationcontext

i am working on a spring 3 web service application and on it i am trying to load the ApplicationContext from my servlett.xml file for use with a simple test case and it doesnt work.

ApplicationContext is always null.

this is my test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:war/WEB-INF/FreedomSpring-servlett.xml" })
    public class UserControllerTest {

        private UserController controller;

        @Inject
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        private String jsonUser = "{ \"username\":\"jonneymendoza\",\"emailAddress\":\"jon@google.com\", \"password\":\"12345678\",\"firstName\":\"jono\", \"surname\":\"richy\", \"country\":\"united kingdom\",\"bio\":\"Bio stuff goes here about the user. where he comes from etc etc. all is well. lets go go go\" }";

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            controller = new UserController();

            assertNotNull(applicationContext);

        }

        @Test
        public void testLogin() {
            fail("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Test
        public void testCreateNewAccount() {

            ResponseEntity<String> response = controller
                    .createNewAccount(new HttpEntity<String>(jsonUser));
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());

        }

        @Test
        public void testGetUserProfile() {
            fail("Not yet implemented");
        }

    }
```

It fails on setup as applicationContext is null. i want to basicaly load up my beans on this test case and use them here but autowiring the UserService class object as shown below in my controller class.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
```

xml file that defines my service beans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- Define services here-->

    <bean id="userService" class="com.jr.freedom.user.UserService"></bean>



</beans>
```

servett below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="mvc-config.xml" />

    <import resource="service-config.xml" />

    <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jr.freedom.controllers"></context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

What am i missing?

edit: i am npw getting this error in the console output

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:146)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

**Another edit:** fixed the above junit error by using junit 4.4 instead. Now we are back to the original issue in regards to the ApplicatyionContext.

this is the error stack trace whenever i run my test:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.buildApplicationContext(TestContext.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: If you're using a file you'd likely need to make sure that either (a) you've explicitly set the test execution directory, or (b) specify the complete pathname. IMO it's much easier to just use a classpath resource.

Comment: Can you see the log while your app is trying to build the `ApplicationContext` ? There must be some error, and you could get help from that log.

Comment: i have specified the complete pathname under "file:war/WEB-INF/FreedomSpring-servlett.xml" but it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: @DaveNewton the problem with that is that WEB-INF is not on the classpath.

Comment: yea it is not in the classpath. this is the standard way of creating a simple spring mvc/web service

Comment: I too am used to `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml"})`. And `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

Comment: The exception looks to be introduced by addition of @RunWith. Looks like a version mismatch between Spring (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner) and JUnit. New problem looks like.

Comment: yea i fixed that issue now, need to use junit 4.4

Comment: Using a file path for this is very fragile. Use a classpath resource instead, and make sure the resource is on the classpath, in the correct folder.

Comment: The Web-inf should never be placed in classpath as far as i know

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I understand it's not--that's why I said to make sure the relative path makes sense in the execution environment or to use a fully-qualified path. *Or* put it on the classpath, which IMO is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation is missing, or was just a mistake when copy and paste?

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but hopefully it will help you troubleshoot (it did for me). Add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to your class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:///c:/project/target/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SpringContextTest {
   ...
}
```

This will at least give you the logging, so it will be easier to see what's going on. Either it's incorrect file path, or a problem inside the context definition, e.g. an invalid bean definition.

NB: Nevermind the absolute path in my example, this was part of an experiment - it should really rely on a `classpath:` location.

**UPDATE:** The updated stacktrace suggests that you don't have the Java Servlets API on the classpath when running your tests (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException). Make sure to include the jar `servlet-api-2.5.jar` (or similar) on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks. i now get this: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

which indicated that it cant find my database.properties file? its under the exact same location as the FreedomSpring-servlet.xml file under web-inf.

see OP for full servlet.xml code. maybe i need to specify full path again?

Comment: Yes, but generally it will try to find properties on the classpath. Make sure it is on the classpath for tests.

Comment: Thanks mate. i fixed that but now getting another issue but anyways the initial problem of getting applicationContext is fixed therefore i will close this thread and mark your answer as the answered one. again thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this issue for 3-4 hours..but finally when I added the below code to my test class ....

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:///D:/PRMS_Workspace/PRMS/WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" })
```

It worked out.